# Auto Load More Data from MongoDB on Page Scroll with Jquery & PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mongodb

I Want autoload more data on page scroll so I tried following:
Index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Auto Load More Data on Page Scroll with Jquery & PHP</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <h2 align="center">Auto Load More Data on Page Scroll with Jquery & PHP</a></h2>
   <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" value="para" placeholder="Search by Name" class="form-control" />
   <br />
   <div id="load_data"></div>
   <div id="load_data_message"></div>
   <br />
   <br />
   <br />
   <br />
   <br />
   <br />
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

 var limit = 7;
 var start = 0;
 var action = 'inactive';
 function load_country_data(limit, start,query)
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{limit:limit, start:start, query:query},
   cache:false,
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#load_data').append(data);
    if(data == '')
    {
     $('#load_data_message').html("<button type='button' class='btn btn-info'>No Data Found</button>");
     action = 'active';
    }
    else
    {
     $('#load_data_message').html("<button type='button' class='btn btn-warning'>Please Wait....</button>");
     action = "inactive";
    }
   }
  });
 }

 if(action == 'inactive')
 {
  action = 'active';
  load_country_data(limit, start);
 }
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#load_data").height() && action == 'inactive')
  {
   action = 'active';
   start = start + limit;
   setTimeout(function(){
    load_country_data(limit, start);
   }, 1000);
  }
 });

});
</script>
```

above code sends post request to fetch.php with search query and skip and limit.
and fetch.php got data sends by index.php and process it and sends back the output back to index page.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$output = '';
$search = '';

if(isset($_POST["limit"],$_POST["start"],$_POST["query"]))
{
    $search = $_POST["query"];
    $limit = $_POST["limit"];
    $skip = $_POST["start"];
    echo "Searching for ";
    echo $search;
    echo "<BR>";
    $output .= '<div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>basics</th>
                            <th>Manufacturer</th>
                            <th>Get full Details</th>
                        </tr>';
    echo $output;

$client = new MongoDB\Client();
$c1 = $client->testdb->{'data360'};
$queryString = ".*".$search.".*";
$query = array(
    '$or' => array(
        array(
            'name' => array (
                '$regex' => new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex($queryString),
                '$options' => 'i'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'pre.basics' => array (
                '$regex' => new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex($queryString),
                '$options' => 'i'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'Pre.Manufacturer' => array (
                '$regex' => new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex($queryString),
                '$options' => 'i'
            )
        ),
     )
);

$options = [
    'skip' => $start,
    'limit' => $limit
];

$cursor = $c1->find($query,$options);
//$results = $c->aggregate($ops);
//var_dump($cursor);
foreach ($cursor as $document) {
    $output = '
    <tr>
        <td>'.$document['name'].'</td>
        <td>'.$document['Pre']['basics'].'</td>
        <td>'.$document['Pres']['Manufacturer'].'</td>
    </tr>
';

echo $output;
}
}

else
{
    // the array of product criteria
}

?>
```

where it goes wrong? and why its not working..? Give me solution to this problem...

Comment: is `fetch.php` triggered?